# pytest coverage reports differently both locally and on CI

Tags: pytest, code-coverage

I write a Django boilerplate here: https://github.com/trouchet/tarzan. So far, so good! On a file `Makefile`, I write the following target, and run `make report` when I need to see how development is going:

```
report: clean test ## Add a rule to generate coverage report
    coverage report
    coverage html
    $(BROWSER) htmlcov/index.html
```

I also have a test workflow here for both test run and report upload here: https://github.com/trouchet/tarzan/blob/main/.github/workflows/test.yml. However, as you can see on my coverage badge, there is only 21% code covered, while the report states 75% locally.

I cannot find fron where does this difference comes from. Please, would you mind helping me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I believe --omit parameter from workflow yml is the reason

```
poetry run coverage run --rcfile=.coveragerc --omit='tests/*,setup/*' -m pytest
```